# How do we actually do list sorting in Google Bookmarks (alphabetical order)

Tags: sorting, google-bookmarks

I use Google Bookmarks and I’d need a way to sort all my lists in alphabetical order.

The "My lists" current has itself sorted in last modified order... and although that’s useful, it is more useful to list it in alphabetical order.

Comment: My lists sort alphabetically by default and I don't see a way to change that.

Comment: @Al holy how did you do that?

Comment: I didn't *do* anything. I just started making lists (since I didn't have any), added them in reverse alphabetical order, and they appeared in alphabetical order.

Comment: @Al well u know something, it isn't arranged in alphabetical but rather in last modified order. that means when you start adding stuff to those lists, the lists will no longer be ordered alphabetically.

Comment: Yup, you're right. Please ignore my red herring.

Answer (score 1):

For non-Google Chrome users, here is a procedure for Windows 7:

Click on START and then click on your user name to access the Favorites list in your user folder.

- Open the Favorites folder and sort it alphabetically.
- Create a new folder using a name that will get it to the top of your Favorites list.
- Copy the sorted Favorites list into your new folder. The first time you do this you may have to answer OK to a Windows security question.
- Close the files; open Google; open the Favorites list and click on your new folder. You should have favorites sorted straight alpha.

Periodically repeat the process to add your latest Favorites to the alphabetized list.

For an alternative way to get to your user folder:

- click Start;
- click Computer;
- click on your primary disk drive;
- click on Users;
- click on your user name.

Answer (score -1):

The left hand nav of Google Bookmarks has

### **Sort by**

[Title](https://www.google.com/bookmarks/l#!view=threadsmgmt&fo=Starred&q=&g=Title)

[Date](https://www.google.com/bookmarks/l#!view=threadsmgmt&fo=Starred&q=&g=Time)

The **Title** option is an alphabetical sort.

Comment: when i click "My List - see all" the sort by option disappears..

Comment: You maybe right ... sorry I don't use lists  and assumed the options would still be there.

Comment: so its there no way to sort lists.. (i can't believe this to be the case..)

Comment: heys delete your answer